# How to add GIMP to the www-data group?

Tags: permissions, gimp

My GIMP cant access files in the /var/www/html folder where I run my projects on localhost. I assume I have to add GIMP to the www-data group, right?

My user is already a member of the www-data group and I have write access via any file manager but GIMP still cant access files in the /var/www/html folder.

Comment: Programs have the privileges of the user that runs them, [unless they are set-uid](https://www.linuxnix.com/suid-set-suid-linuxunix/). Gimp is *not*, and *should not* be, suid binary.

Comment: Why does somebody constantly mark this question as duplicate when it clearly is not? My question is about a program, GIMP to be specific, the referenced answer talks about files.
@vidarlo: What does GIMP not should be? Thanks for the linked article but it does not make any sense to my layman brain, I am a user, not a sys admin. I can install a program and use it.

Comment: A program like GIMP has the privileges of the user. If your user can edit the files, he can do so using gimp.The duplicate explains how to configure it so your user has access to the files.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But as I said in the initial question: my user is already a member of the www-data group and I have write access via any file manager. So why does GIMP not have the same rights like my file managers do? Thanks.

Comment: @hleg Is there an apparmor profile for it?

Comment: @xenoid: I searched in the Ubuntu menu but there is no "apparmor profile" software installed.

Comment: I still cant believe how condescending some moderators in this community are. "This question already has answers here: " My question is about a program, GIMP to be specific, the referenced answer talks about files. And on top of that they close a question that is not even theirs, and although it clearly is not answered yet ... just stunning